# MongoDB - Error handling for non-existent field

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I have a collection with a set of field values for each document. One of these is called 'coordinates'. Now when I'm querying the DB for and for elements that are not null for this field, it returns the right values as I'm expecting.

However I run into this error now and then in python (Pymongo):

```
if not doc['coordinates']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

This seems to imply that it has come across a record where there is no field 'coordinates'. I've created the document to have this field and should exist.

I want to know though, how can I handle this error and to prevent this error from terminating my program.

This is how I find the appropriate queries:

```
 cursor = collection.find(
                { "$and" : [
                    {"term": {"$in": events}}, 
                    { "$or" : [
                            {"coordinates" : {"$ne": None}}, 
                            {"place" : {"$ne" : None}}
                    ]}
                ]}, 
            {"term" : 1, "coordinates" : 1, "place" : 1, "time_normal" : 1}, tailable = True, timeout = False )
```

I then iterate through the returned queries, as:

```
while cursor.alive:
    try:
        doc = cursor.next()

        CODE IS HERE TO QUERY DB


    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting a `TypeError` in your example and an `AttributeError` in the example that nickmilon supplied is because the query that you're using to get your `doc` is not finding anything (and is therefore a `NoneType`). Check your query to make sure that you're actually getting things out of your collection.

The answer that nickmilon supplies should give you the error handling you're after, though.

Comment: Thanks, yes the query is returning documents . In this instance it will return several hundred documents before encountering this error. So would it be that it is hitting a document with no coordinate field?

Comment: I'll second @nickmilion above and suggest that you try a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop. Seems like it might make the code a bit easier to follow, too.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:  doc.get('coordinates')   it will return None if field does not exist or its value if exists

Comment: If I try that it still gives me a similar error:     if not doc.get('coordinates'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Answer (score 1):

Eric is right, for some reason your doc is None. Could you post here the code you are using for find and how you process the cursor returned from find ?

Comment: Hi, I've updated my original question with the requested code fragment

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with your code. May be you try : for doc in cursor: foo=doc.get("coordinates")

Answer (score 0):

I was able to handle this error by including the TypeError in the exception block, as:

```
                try:                                               
                    if not doc['coordinates']:
                        CODE HERE

                    else: 
                        CODE HERE

                except (TypeError):
                    pass
```